# How to remove (make disappear) Rive animation when it has finished it's animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rive

I created a flutter Rive `oneshotAnimation`, and I want it to be disappear from the screen when the animation is over. Currently animation stays on the screen when animation is over, and I cant interact with the other widgets on the screen because of that. Luckily there is `onStop` function in `oneshotAnimation` controller. Could someone please tell me how to implement this part?

```
late RiveAnimationController _partAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _partAnimation = OneShotAnimation(
      'Animation',
      onStop: () {},  // I want to remove the rive animation from the screen when it is done
    );
  }
```

.... Here is the animation widget

```
       SizedBox(height: 400,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                  'assets/rive/party.riv',
                  antialiasing: false,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  controllers: [_partAnimation],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Override dispose() method and dispose your controller object in it.

Code:

```
late RiveAnimationController _partAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _partAnimation = OneShotAnimation(
      'Animation',
      onStop: () {

      },  // I want to remove the rive animation from the screen when it is done
    );
  }

  //Add dispose method
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _partAnimation.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Step 2: Call dispose() in onStop of OneShotAnimation()

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _partAnimation = OneShotAnimation(
      'Animation',
      onStop: () {
        dispose();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried it. It did not work :(